# compare two value from different dataframe and based on that add value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Need to compare two different Dataframe and based on the result add value to a column

```
country = {'Year':[2020,2021],'Host':['Mexico','Panama'],'Winners':['Canada','Japan']}

country_df = pd.DataFrame(country,columns=['Year','Host','Winners'])
```

```
    Year  Host      Winners
0   2020  Mexico    Canada
1   2021  Panama    Japan
```

```
all_country = {'Country': ['USA','Mexico','USA','Panama','Japan'],'Year':[2021,2020,2020,2021,2021]}
all_country_df=pd.DataFrame(all_country,columns=['Country','Year']
```

```
Country     Year
0   USA     2021
1   Mexico  2020
2   USA     2020
3   Panama  2021
4   Japan   2021
```

I want to compare the all_country_df with the country_df to find which country was the host in the given year as well as the winners so something like

```
all_country= {'Country':['USA','Mexico','USA','Panama','Japan'],'Year':[2021,2020,2020,2021,2021],'Winner':[None,None,None,None,'Winner'],'Host':[None,'Host',None,'Host',None]}
all_Country_df=pd.DataFrame(all_country,columns=['Country','Year','Winner','Host'])
```

Like this

```
    Country Year    Winner  Host
0   USA     2021    None    None
1   Mexico  2020    None    Host
2   USA     2020    None    None
3   Panama  2021    None    Host
4   Japan   2021    Winner  None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `merge` and `np.where`:

```
newdf = all_country_df.merge(country_df)
newdf['Winners'] = np.where(newdf['Country'].ne(newdf['Winner']), np.nan, 'Winners')
newdf['Host'] = np.where(newdf['Country'].ne(newdf['Host']), np.nan, 'Host')
print(newdf)
```

Output:

```
  Country  Year  Host  Winners
0     USA  2021   nan      nan
1  Panama  2021  Host      nan
2   Japan  2021   nan   Winner
3  Mexico  2020  Host      nan
4     USA  2020   nan      nan
```